# ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites timeout

Tags: ravendb

I use `documentStore.Conventions.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites`
statement in my code to query data from RavenDB and it works fine. But how can I set global timeout for all queries like in query below.

```
RavenQueryStatistics stats;
var results = session.Query<Product>()
.Statistics(out stats)
.Where(x => x.Price > 10)
.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a [Document Query Listener](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/advanced/client-side-listeners#document-query-listener)

```cs
public class NonStaleQueryListener(TimeSpan timeout) : IDocumentQueryListener
{
    public void BeforeQueryExecuted(IDocumentQueryCustomization customization)
    {
        customization.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite(timeout);
    }
}
```

And register it like so:

```cs
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
documentStore.RegisterListener(new NonStaleQueryListener(timeout));
```

Comment: WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite, you meant.
And note that this means that ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites is not relevant.